# iPad - UISplitViewController and RTL

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I need to write an iPad app that supports RTL. 
If i use UISplitViewController the content of the master and detail view changes direction when RTL locale is in use (Hebrew, Arabic) but the master view and the details view does not flip.

Is there a way to force the UISplitViewController to flip? Is there another way to do it?